# Induced electric current in a rotating circui

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image] How can we derive a formula for the instantaneous e.m.f. ?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: When posting images, please make them an appropriate size. This could be cut to 1/2 or 1/3 the height.

Comment: These homework-like questions can be found in so many books. I vote for closing it.